# How to list events on Outlook group calendar

Tags: calendar, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-calendar

In my Outlook client, I have access to a Group Calendar, "XYZ Cloud".  Through Outlook, I can  create, edit and delete events on this calendar.

When I use the [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and query [/me/calendars](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars), the Group Calendar is not returned.  I would expect to see the Group Calendar.

I've navigated to the "Modify Permissions" tab in the Graph Explorer and granted Calendars.ReadWrite, Calendars.ReadShared and Calendars.Read.

Questions:

1. How can I get the ID of a specific Group Calendar to which I already have access?
2. How can I retrieve a list of events on that Group Calendar?

Comment: query calendar group events require to consent `Group` related api permission so that you can query group calendar. and follow the sample mentioned in the document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

agree with user2250152, and pls make sure you already add **correct api permission** -- `Group.Read.All, Group.ReadWrite.All`:

[image]

related document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions

Comment: You are right with permissions Group.Read.All, Group.ReadWrite.All. Graph Explorer unfortunately doesn't show that these permissions are required, so call /me/calendarGroups/{id}/calendars can return empty collection without Group.Read.All, Group.ReadWrite.All.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite possible that group calendar can be found when you call

```
GET /me/groupCalendars
```

To list calendars in calendar group you can call

```
GET /me/calendarGroups/{id}/calendars
```

Documentation:

[List group calendars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendargroups?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)